# Why won't my MySQL Podman container run?

Tags: fedora, mysql, podman

I have installed `"Development Tools"` and run the following commands:

```
podman pull mysql:latest                # this is pulled from docker.io

podman images                           # lists the correct image

mkdir ~/mysql_data ; cd mysql_data

podman run -d \
--name mysql \
-p 3306:3306 \
-v ~/mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql \
-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='My password' \
-e MYSQL_USER=dbuser \
-e MYSQL_PASSWORD='My DB password' \
-e MYSQL_DATABASE=testdb \
mysql:latest

podman ps                               # lists no running containers
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE       COMMAND     CREATED     STATUS      PORTS       NAMES

podman ps -a
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                           COMMAND     CREATED        STATUS      PORTS                   NAMES
341ff9ebe686  docker.io/library/mysql:latest  mysqld      7 minutes ago  Created     0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp  mysql
```

However, when I try to execute the next command (`podman exec -it mysql /bin/bash`), I get the following error:

```
Error: can only create exec sessions on running containers: container state improper
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Your command line seems fine. What version of `podman` are you using (on what distribution version)? Do you see anything in the logs for the container (probably not , given the container status, but it can't hurt to check)?

Comment: @larsks found it. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, SELinux doesn't like containers inside your home folder, so the trick is to add a `:Z` to the volume, like this:

```
-v ~/mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql:Z
```